# JavaFX WebView in Java Swing Project

Tags: java, swing, javafx, webview

i try to use the WebView in my java project, in my code is:

```
JFXPanel fxPanel = new JFXPanel();
fxPanel.setBounds(10, 48, 439, 362);
desktopPane.add(fxPanel);

WebView webView = new WebView();
fxPanel.setScene(new Scene(webView));
webView.getEngine().load("http://www.stackoverflow.com/");
```

but the this thown a exception

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not on FX application thread; currentThread = main
```

And yes, this is not a JavaFx application.

Comment: if this isn't a JavaFX application, why are you using it?

Comment: i like to load a website (html5 and css support) in my application :) JEditorPane dont support html5 :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can embed JavaFX content into a Swing application using [`JFXPanel`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/embed/swing/JFXPanel.html). Note that for this to work correctly, you have to be careful to create and access the Swing content on the AWT event dispatch thread, and create and access the JavaFX content on the FX Application Thread, so you will need to carefully manage code using `SwingUtilities.invokeLater(...)` and `Platform.runLater(...)`. (See the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/embed/swing/JFXPanel.html) for more details.)

Creating a `JFXPanel` starts the FX Application toolkit, if it is not already started.

Here is a simple example of embedding a JavaFX `WebView` into a Swing application:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.embed.swing.JFXPanel;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.web.WebView;

public class FXWebViewInSwing {

    private JFXPanel jfxPanel ;

    public void createAndShowWindow() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        JButton quit = new JButton("Quit");
        quit.addActionListener(event -> System.exit(0));
        jfxPanel = new JFXPanel();
        Platform.runLater(this::createJFXContent);

        JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel();
        buttonPanel.add(quit);

        frame.add(BorderLayout.CENTER, jfxPanel);
        frame.add(BorderLayout.SOUTH, buttonPanel);

        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(800,  800);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private void createJFXContent() {
        WebView webView = new WebView();
        webView.getEngine().load("http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42297864/javafx-webview-in-java-project");
        Scene scene = new Scene(webView);
        jfxPanel.setScene(scene);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        FXWebViewInSwing swingApp = new FXWebViewInSwing();
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(swingApp::createAndShowWindow);
    }
}
```

[image]