# JavaFX WebView not loading graph data from url (WebSocket?)

Tags: javafx, webview, javafx-webengine

Using this code and the hardcoded url, the graph in the url doesn't load. I tried disabling my firewall and running it under JDK 9 with a pre-release build of Netbeans 9. No luck. A WebSocket test says that WebSocket is working fine (url commented out in the code). Any ideas what's wrong or what I should check? My guess is it has to do with WebSocket regardless of the test results. I'm using Netbeans 8.2 and jdk1.8.0_144.

```
//
// Code from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42297864/javafx-webview-in-java-project
//
public class FXWebViewInSwing {

    private JFXPanel jfxPanel;

    public void createAndShowWindow() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        JButton quit = new JButton("Quit");
        quit.addActionListener(event -> System.exit(0));
        jfxPanel = new JFXPanel();
        Platform.runLater(this::createJFXContent);

        JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel();
        buttonPanel.add(quit);

        frame.add(BorderLayout.CENTER, jfxPanel);
        frame.add(BorderLayout.SOUTH, buttonPanel);

        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(1024, 576);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private void createJFXContent() {
        WebView webView = new WebView();
        webView.getEngine().load("https://www.tradingview.com/chart/bKsZf5LY/");
//        webView.getEngine().load("https://websocket.org/echo.html");
        Scene scene = new Scene(webView);
        jfxPanel.setScene(scene);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        FXWebViewInSwing swingApp = new FXWebViewInSwing();
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(swingApp::createAndShowWindow);
    }
}
```