# Implement a map image into Java / JFrame

Tags: java, jframe, openstreetmap

The plan is to implement a map (like OpenStreetMap) into Java. Zoomable and movable. I tried implementing them via JOSM or screenshotted HTML website and many other libraries and extensions. None of my efforts seem to work and I'm out of ideas.
Another function i tried to implement is a savable screenshot of the map as to have an offline image.
Here's my last effort (JEditorPane):

```
public static void create() {
        jf = new JFrame("DFA SanD");
        jf.setSize(Var.ScreenWidth, Var.ScreenHeight);
        jf.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        jf.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        jf.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
        jf.setAutoRequestFocus(true);
        jf.setResizable(false);
        jf.setUndecorated(true);
        
        
        JEditorPane jEditorPane = new JEditorPane();
        URL url = null;
        try {
            url = new URL("https://www.openstreetmap.org/export/embed.html?bbox=8.410876393318178%2C52.004401229481466%2C8.41854751110077%2C52.00715529696299&amp;layer=mapnik");
        } catch (MalformedURLException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {   
           jEditorPane.setPage(url);
        } catch (IOException e) { 
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        jEditorPane.setVisible(true);
        jf.add(jEditorPane);
        
        
        d = new Draw();
        d.setVisible(true);
        jf.add(d);
        jf.setVisible(true);
    }
```

Comment: Do you need a web view? Something like in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42299506/4688321 ?

Comment: A `JEditorPane` cannot handle the javascript powering that openstreetmap web page.  15 years ago, you could grab the individual 256 x 256 pixel tiles at each zoom level and stitch together your own `BufferedImage`.  This is (was?) the only way you can use openstreetmap with native Java Swing.

Comment: It looks like you can still get to the individual 256 x 256 pixel raster images.  [Raster tile providers](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Raster_tile_providers)